# Add Dark Background Cover to Existing Website

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I would like to add a dark semi-transparent background image to cover up the background when the user is filling out a form. I am wondering how you would do this as my current implementation is not working.

Currently, when I am trying to implement it, the semi-transparent background does not horizontally stretch the entire width of the page, and seems to create an unwanted chunk of vertical space at the bottom of the page. My existing solution involves creating a div and using `position:relataive; top:-1100px; left:0px;` to place this div exactly where I want.

On the website, this semi-transparent background is located on the fourth and last page named 'Find Us'. By clicking on the tassel labeled 'Feedback' will reveal a form. Currently, it is difficult to read the form because of the busy background, so I wanted to use a semi-transparent background cover to 'blur' out everything on this current page except for the form.

Demo of before I attempted to add the semi-transparent background: http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/it/website01/template.html

Demo of after my attempt of adding the semi-transparent background:
http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/it/website02/template.html

Comment: There's a `</selected>` end tag in your source. Should be `</select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS for `#cover`:

```
#cover {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the height and width and do `right: 0; bottom: 0;` too.

Answer (score 1):

You have the z-index of cover div more than the tassel div. Set the z-index of tassel div to 120 and you already have cover with z-index 115. Check if that works.

Comment: Haha. I didn't notice that. Thank you for picking it up for me :)